# Combine columns in choice list Symfony form

Tags: drop-down-menu, symfony, choicefield

In my Symfony form I have a choiceType field listing categories. My categorie table looks like this:

```
id code categorie
1  100  First categorie
2  200  Second categorie
3  210  Second subcategorie
```

In my form I have a selectfield and with 'choice_label' I can decide which column, either 'code' or 'categorie' to use for the select list. I would like to use both so the user has a selectlist showing:

- 100 First categorie
- 200 Second categorie
- .. etc

Is it possible to join the 2 columns for the choice_label; Concatenate the 2 columns in a string just for the purpose of the selectoptions to show?
I have tried to find it here and elsewhere. The official [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label) do not mention this option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even in ChoiceType for choice_label you can use callable to set it [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#advanced-example-with-objects)

```
'choice_label' => function($category, $key, $index) {
    /** @var Category $category */
    return $category->getId() . ' ' . $category->getName();
},
```

But why do you use ChoiceType for you categories, how do you going to set choices? Why don't you use [EntityType?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

```
->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
    'choice_label' => function ($category) {
        return $category->getId() . ' ' . $category->getName();
    },
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');
    },
))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Btw: I did use EntityType for this select field, but did not say so in my question, guess I was too focused on the choice-aspect. The function for joining the 2 columns works great.